# Export and Import tables (not data) using pgAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

With pgAdmin, on my created DB, I have seven tables (all of them have at least one primary key, and some of them include foreign keys). Let's suppose in a moment I need to do a mayor correction so I don't have no other choice that to move it to another DB, and I don't want to rewrite the characteristics of the seven tables over and over again.

So, with that said, how I can export my tables (the structure, not the data), so, when I create another DB with pgAdmin, I can import my tables previously created.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table new (
    like old
    including defaults
    including constraints
    including indexes
);
```

REF [Copy table structure into new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220453/copy-table-structure-into-new-table)

Comment: I read the reference, and it doesn't work form me because at least half of the tables have foreign keys.

Comment: in that case you gotta do some extra work.. read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359968/restore-postgresql-db-from-backup-without-foreign-key-constraint-issue

Answer (score 1):

With pgAdmin 1.14 and prior releases, there were only two ways to insert data in a table:
use the restore tool (which uses pg_restore) ;
use the query tool to execute INSERT queries (COPY queries are allowed if they use a file, but not stdin/stdout).
[This link would help you](http://blog.guillaume.lelarge.info/index.php/post/2012/02/25/An-import-tool-for-pgAdmin)